# Mathematica 11.3 no longer uses CodeAssistHistory Information to Order Autocomplete Results?

Tags: front-end, autocomplete, version-11.3

In previous versions of Mathematica I'm reasonably sure that the auto suggestions that appear when you begin typing were ordered by the frequency when you would use them. (I.e. typing "In" would result in "Integrate" being first in the list if you used Integrate[] a lot).

I believe 11.3 seems to have broken this, since no matter how I change the values in CodeAssistHistory, I'm unable to get any ordering other than the default one, which leads to more obscure/less-used functions appearing at the top of the autosuggest list and thus requiring more keystrokes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was not the case, at least not for all machines I use because I'd have `EvaluationNotebook` on top as soon as I start typing `eval`, that is not the case and I'm often annoyed by this fact.

Comment: @Kuba That might be the case. What are the frequencies recorded in CodeAssistHistory used for then?

Comment: I'd guess that exactly for this but either it is just waiting for a green light for this feature or there is a front end option I'm missing that makes all my installations and your 11.3 affected. Maybe there is a quick switch, let's wait for someone else to join :)